# SSRS not repeat subTablix header

Tags: reporting-services

I must finish my report.

I put subTablix in my main Tablix，I want the subTablix header repeat once

But I don't know how to do it, please help me, thanks.

Before I run the report:

i.stack.imgur.com/7cx44.png

After I run the report:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/g448K.png

I wish my report become:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LePKc.png

Answer (score 0):

You need to group by the field which contains the subTablix header. The details row will then be the rows below that.